# Recurrence Relation Involving the gamma Function

Tags: recurrence-relations, gamma-function

I'm having some doubts about my approach to the following problem. I am given that the function $k(z)$ is defined such that,

$$k(z)=\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+z\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-z\right)\cos{\pi z}$$

I'm required to find the recurrence relation linking $k(z+1)$ and $k(z)$ and to then evaluate $k(z)$ for one specific integer value and thus find $k(z)$ for any real, integer value. My attempt was as follows.

Note that $\Gamma(s+1)=s\Gamma(s)$ and so

\begin{align*}
k(z+1)&=\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+z+1\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-z+1\right)\cos{(\pi z + \pi)} \\
&=\left(\frac{1}{2}+z\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+z\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}-z\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-z\right)\cos{(\pi z + \pi)}
\end{align*}

Then since $\cos{(\pi z + \pi)}=-\cos{\pi z}$ we have that

$$k(z+1)=\left(z^2-\frac{1}{4}\right)k(z)$$

If we then consider the case $z=0$, we have

$$k(0)=\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\pi$$

From this we see that

\begin{align*}
&k(1)=-\frac{1}{4}\pi\\
&k(2)=-\frac{3}{16}\pi\\
&k(3)=-\frac{45}{64}\pi\\
&\vdots
\end{align*}

I can't spot any pattern here other than the $4^z$ in the denominator which is making me think i've done something wrong, maybe in my use of $\Gamma(s+1)=s\Gamma(s)$? Any advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: You have a mistake in the first line of the recurrence for $k\left(\, z + 1\,\right)$. It should be $\Gamma\left(\,{1 \over 2} - z \color{#c00000}{\ {\Large - 1}}\,\right)$ instead of $\Gamma\left(\,{1 \over 2} - z \color{#c00000}{+ 1}\,\right)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a sign error.
\begin{align}
\frac{k(n+1)}{k(n)}
&=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+n+1\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-n\color{red}{-1}\right)(-\cos(\pi n))}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+n\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-n\right)\cos(\pi n)}\\
&=\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}+n\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+n\right)\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-n\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{2}-n-1\right)}(-1)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+n\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-n\right)}\\
&=-\frac{\frac{1}{2}+n}{-\frac{1}{2}-n}\\
&=1
\end{align}
Hence $k(n)=k(0)=\pi$.

Comment: I can't believe I made such an obvious mistake, thank you, that would explain why the recurrence relation in the previous answer seemed so difficult to spot!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\quad\Gamma(1+z)~\Gamma(1-z)=\dfrac{\pi z}{\sin\pi z}\qquad$ and $\qquad\Gamma\bigg(\dfrac12+z\bigg)~\Gamma\bigg(\dfrac12-z\bigg)=\dfrac\pi{\cos\pi z}$

See [Euler's reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula), [Legendre's duplication formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreDuplicationFormula.html), and [Gauss' multiplication theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem).

Comment: A very sketchy proof of the former can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/714668/1).

Comment: Ah, I have come across the reflection formula for $\Gamma(1+z)\Gamma(1-z)$ but not the second, that should be useful, thank you!

Comment: (+1) I have usually seen the Reflection Formula as $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\frac\pi{\sin(\pi z)}$, but your formula follows since $z\Gamma(z)=\Gamma(z+1)$

Answer (score 1):

Note that using the identity you've developed,
$$
\begin{align}
k(n)
&=k(0)\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\left(j^2-\frac14\right)\\
&=\frac\pi{4^n}\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(2j-1)(2j+1)\\
&=\frac\pi{4^n}(-1\cdot1)(1\cdot3)(3\cdot5)\cdots\big((2n-3)\cdot(2n-1)\big)\\
&=\frac\pi{4^n}\frac{-1}{2n-1}(1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n-1))^2\\
&=\frac\pi{4^n}\frac{-1}{2n-1}\left(\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}\right)^2
\end{align}
$$
This matches the sequence you've listed.

---

**Euler's Reflection Formula**

[Euler's Reflection Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General) for the Gamma Function is proven in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/176216):
$$
\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\pi\csc(\pi z)
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\Gamma\left(\frac12-z\right)\Gamma\left(\frac12+z\right)
&=\pi\csc\left(\frac\pi2-\pi z\right)\\
&=\pi\sec(\pi z)
\end{align}
$$
This means that
$$
\Gamma\left(\frac12-z\right)\Gamma\left(\frac12+z\right)\cos(\pi z)=\pi
$$
This indicates there is a problem, which Guest543212345 has pointed out.

Comment: Thank you, I never would've spotted this myself!

Comment: @Jamie3213: You will when you gain a bit more experience with products such as this.